# Making code snippets editable (not necessarily savable) by all users

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I'm finding lately I really hate code-snippets. Someone (often myself) posts a code snippet in their question. This is great because I can see the code actually run. But... then I want to try to modify it to see if I can solve the problem. I can't. My only option is to actually click "edit" then I can click "edit this snippet" and now I can finally play with the snippet then later click "cancel".

This makes are arguably still much better to use an external site like jsfiddle because it allows people to "fiddle" with the code.

Can SO be updated to allow fiddling with the code? A button a user can click that opens the SO snippet editor? They don't need to be able to save (although a "copy this snippet to a new answer" might be a cool addition as well.

Some people will say click "Copy Snippet to Answer"

That has several issues

1. I might have no intent to create an answer.

   Choosing to do something "create an answer" is not the same as fiddling the code
2. I don't want a snippet in my answer.

   I'm creating an answer where I only want to mention what to change. Copying some giant snippet into my answer makes editing the answer a pain in the ass
3. It's a horrible UX. Stack Overflow should be doing better.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of every snippet is a big blue button saying "Copy snippet to answer". Just press it and fiddle away in the answer box.

[image]

Comment: I didn't want to create an answer. I wanted to fiddle with the code.

Comment: And what stops you using this method to fiddle with the code?

Comment: Because it's a pain in the ass to clean up out of my answer and makes editing my answer which will not include a snippet much harder to edit